# Is $\Bbb Z / n \Bbb Z$ a PID?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

I’d like to when $\Bbb Z / n \Bbb Z$ is a PID. I don’t know if depends of the value of $n$, it is true for all $n$ or $\Bbb Z / n \Bbb Z$ is never a PID. No idea. In case it’s true I’d like to see the proof (without group theory) .

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: principal ideal *domains* are, in particular, integral domains.

Comment: @Wojowu $R=\Bbb Z / n \Bbb Z$ is a integral domain iff $n$ is prime. I guess that if $n$ is prime, then $R$ is perhaps a PID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that a Principal Ideal **Ring** is a ring $R$ in which every ideal is principal.

**Theorem.** Let $R$ be a principal ideal ring, and let $I$ be an ideal of $R$. Then $R/I$ is also a principal ideal ring.

*Proof.* Let $J$ be an ideal of $R/I$, and let $K=\{r\in R\mid r+I\in J\}$ be the pullback of $J$ to $R$. Since $R$ is a principal ideal ring, we know that there exists $a\in R$ such that $K=(a)$. I claim that $(a+I) = J$.

Since $a\in K$, then $a+I\in J$, so $(a+I)\subseteq J$. Conversely, let $x\in J$. Then $x=r+I$ for some $r\in R$, and hence $r\in K$. Therefore, $r\in (a)$, so we can write $r$ as (note that I’m not assuming $R$ is commutative or has a unity):
$$r = na + xa + ay + \sum_{i=1}^m x_iay_i$$
where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, $m\in\mathbb{N}$, $x,y,x_i,y_i\in R$. Then
$$\begin{align*}
x &= r+I\\
&= (na + xa + ay + \sum_{i=1}^mx_iay_i) + I\\
&= n(a+I) + (x+I)(a+I) + (a+I)(y+I)\\
&\qquad + \sum_{i=1}^m (x_i+I)(a+I)(y_i+I)
\end{align*}$$
which lies in $(a+I)$. 
Thus, $J\subseteq (a+I)$, proving the desired equality.~$\Box$

Thus, since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID, hence a principal ideal ring, it follows that for any $n$, $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is always a principal ideal **ring.**

In particular, $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is a principal ideal **domain** if and only if it is a domain. And this happens if and only if $n\mathbb{Z}$ is a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$, which happens if and only if $n$ is a prime number.

Comment: Thanks! But I still have a question. In $\Bbb Z / 12 \Bbb Z$ every ideal is principal but 12 is not prime. Why?

Comment: @mug_donut: Because it’s a principal ideal **ring**; as the theorem says. It’s not a principal ideal *domain* because $12$ is not prime. “PID” stands for Principal Ideal **DOMAIN**. A Domain is a commutative ring with $1\neq 0$ and no nonzero zero divisors.

Comment: Is there any characterization for principal ideal ring? How can I prove that in Z/12Z every ideal is principal?

Comment: @mug_donut: A principal ideal ring is a ring in which every ideal is principal. As to how you can prove that, *did you read the theorem that I posted*? I mean, **it’s right there!** Do you have questions about the theorem? About the proof? Or did you just skip the answer and go straight to asking questions about it?